# javascript eval v.s. browser console tampering, in terms of security differences

Tags: javascript, security

Is there anything different in what you can do with `eval` v.s. what you can do in the browser developer console? is it not safer to use `eval`, as at least, your code evaluates the user input in a certain context, and, it can also log (and scan) the input prior to execution....

Comment: can you explain what you ask?

Comment: a user can always access the javascript console, or inject script into your page that will execute. the difference with eval is that you run the risk of executing user-generated code on another user's machine.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "*your code evaluates the user input in a certain context, and, it can also log (and scan) the input prior to execution*". Btw, the dev console does use `eval` just as well

Comment: Frankly I am not impressed with the inaccuracies, lack of focus and weak relation of the comments/answer to the security focus of my question, but I'll just leave it open anyway... for those who only really ingest titles, I elaborated that focus to the title of the question now.

Answer (score 0):

**`Browser console` and `eval()` are two different things...**
*in my opinion* **can't be compared** *just like that*.

- ***Browser console*** its built into browser <sup>*(and as it, it's browser specific `javascript interpreter`)*</sup>
  Lets you execute code besides many other things.

> [[image]firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) The Web Console: Logs information associated with a web page: any network requests,
>   JavaScript, CSS, security errors and warnings as well as error,
>   warning and informational messages explicitly logged by JavaScript
>   code running in the page context Enables you to interact with a web
>   page by executing JavaScript expressions in the context of the page.
>
> **The [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) is like the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), but applied to the whole
>   browser rather than a single content tab.*

---

> [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) The [Chrome DevTools Console panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/javascript/console/) is your focal point for direct
>   interaction with a page in real time. The Console lets you use
>   standard JavaScript statements and Console-specific commands while a
>   page is live in the browser to help you debug the page. View
>   diagnostic messages, display both raw and structured data, control and
>   filter output, examine and modify page elements, measure execution
>   time, and more.

---

- ***eval()*** its a *`javascript method`*

> The [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

---

*So yes, there's a BIG difference between them and **what you can do**...

...but most important is **how you do it.***

Now, you ask about *security implications with both "options"*, but I think this is too ambiguous in the way you pose the question, could be *user specific answer* depending on how we interpret about what you're trying to clarify..

***I believe you will need to clarify/elaborate a little more your question and give us some real examples of what you're after.***
<sup>or maybe not, and this *mini* explanation is enough to clarify your doubt</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I guess using `eval` within your code runs in the context where `eval` is being called in your code, whereas the developer console can only access globals, and hence can only access your code-as-written but not necessarily live data created by its execution, but am not sure about that nor about loopholes.